# CoCreateInstance fails with 0x80131500

Tags: c#, .net, c, com, com-interop

We're trying to access .NET COM library from unmanaged C code.

```
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(XYZClient::XClient), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pCl));
```

The result of hr is `0x80131500` which means that exception was thrown by COM library.
But when debugging, it doesn't even goes into constructor of our .NET class.

This works fine when called from .NET via COM.

Any ideas how to at least get exception message?

EDIT: It works just fine on Windows XP but fails on Win7 x64.

Comment: You could use Windbg to dig further http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/08/24/managed-debugging-with-windbg-breaking-on-an-exception-part-1.aspx

Comment: Do you have the typelib registered for this class?

Comment: Yes everything is properly registered. The problem was in dependent libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by differences in libraries. Some libraries were available only as 32 bit assemblies which caused this issue. Because of this loading of our COM library failed even before entering constructor code.